# Prefiltering a query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to optimize a query that takes ages, I cannot add any new indexes to the database but I found a way to cut the execution time in half regardless. The solution was to prefilter the query using only some of the WHERE conditions, return the ids and run the rest of the conditions on those ids. I'm wondering if its possible to do this without the round-trip

A minimal example of the original query (not the actual query but same idea):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as total 
FROM 
    my_db.bananas AS b, 
    my_db.bananas_specs as s
WHERE 
    b.created BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND b.gone_bad = false
    AND b.id = s.id
    AND s.is_cool = true
```

My new queries that together run in half the time:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') as ids
FROM
    my_db.bananas
WHERE
    created BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
```

and

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as total
FROM 
    my_db.bananas AS b, 
    my_db.bananas_specs as s
WHERE 
    b.id in (...result of first query)
    AND b.gone_bad = false
    AND b.id = s.id
    AND s.is_cool = true
```

I know there are variables in mysql and that its possible to run multiple select statements in a single query as google tells me it is so but I can't get any of it to work, the error messages php gives me are not very helpful. Essentially, how can I do the second two queries as separate select statements within a single query?

Answer (score 0):

The with statement is very useful for optimising code readability issues -
Having the base data selected before joining to the second table can improve , but not dramatically.

Counting just one column can improve performance rather than counting the whole data set

e.g.

```
with cte_bananas as (
SELECT id, created, gone_bad
  from my_db.bananas 
 where created BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
) -- end with cte_bananas
select count(1) as Total
  from cte_bananas b
  inner join my_db.bananas_specs as s
  on s.id = b.id
 where b.gone_bad = false
   and s.is_cool = true
```

As your query is a snippet there may be some experimenting necessary here.

Comment: `b.gone_bad = false` conditoin can be moved into CTE too (with removing `gone_bad` and `created` from CTE's output list - you don't need in them in outer query).

Comment: @Akina You'd think that but for whatever reason, including gone_bad in the first select annihalates any performance gain.

As for this answer - I failed to mention, I'm working with mysql 5.6 and I don't think it supports this

Comment: @user81993 This means that the index by `bananas (created)` exists but by `bananas (created, gone_bag)` not exists. If you provided CREATE TABLE for tables, it would be easier to see what is applicable and what is not applicable. Anycase `created` may be removed from subquery's output list.

Comment: @Akina - good call moving the {gone_bad = false} to the cte - but - if performance is noted on the selection criteria (reading from disk) - with the data in memory (by virtue of the cte) then this filter would be quicker outside the main selection.  Really depends on the nature of the indexing on the table - as ever :)

Comment: @Akina neither created or gone_bad has an index, only ID is indexed

Comment: @user81993 In this case moving the condition into the subquery must improve. Except the case when more than a half of rows matches `gone_bad = false`..

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of using version mysql 5.6 - - create a view with the base bananas records and then create a separation selection query

```
create view vw_bananas_inPeriod as
SELECT id, created, gone_bad
  from my_db.bananas 
 where created BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Next - assemble the query

```
select count(1) as Total
  from vw_bananas_inPeriod b
  inner join my_db.bananas_specs as s
  on s.id = b.id
 where b.gone_bad = false
   and s.is_cool = true
```